# Split Mac address in a list python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I need to extract last two digits in all Mac address stored in a python list.

```
['00:00:00:00:00:02',
 '00:00:00:00:00:01',
 '00:00:00:00:00:03',
 '00:00:00:00:00:01',
 '00:00:00:00:00:04',
 '00:00:00:00:00:01']
```

from this list i need to extract [02,01,03,01,04,01]
or 
is there a method in panda dataframe for this ?

Comment: `[x.rsplit(':')[-1] for x in L]` or `[x[-2:] for x in L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rsplit` by last separator and seelct last value by position:

```
L = ['00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03',
     '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04', '00:00:00:00:00:01']

out = [x.rsplit(':', 1)[-1] for x in L]
#alternative
#out = [x.split(':')[-1] for x in L]
```

Or get last 2 values per each value of string by indexing:

```
out = [x[-2:] for x in L]
```

---

```
print (out)
['02', '01', '03', '01', '04', '01']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
macs = ['00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04', '00:00:00:00:00:01']
short_macs = [x[-2:] for x in macs]
```

output

```
['02', '01', '03', '01', '04', '01']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do your work

```
data=['00:00:00:00:00:02', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:03', '00:00:00:00:00:01', '00:00:00:00:00:04', '00:00:00:00:00:01']
last_digits=[mac_address.split(':')[-1] for mac_address in data]
print(last_digits)
```